# Dualbooting Ubuntu 16.04.1 - Win 10 Partition Problem

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows

I'm trying to install Ubuntu as my second OS on the same HDD as Win 10. I'm having some trouble downloading Ubuntu into the partition I've set aside for it. On the install screen, it just gives me a sort of memory slider where I can choose how much of my primary drive I want to dedicate. I can't seem to figure out why it won't give me the option to load into the empty partition.

This is what my disk manager is showing (the F drive is just my USB drive, and I've renamed the empty partition "Ubuntu"):

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I should add that when I looked at the other options, there weree only a few other partitions to choose from. One of which was the win 10 system reserved along with two or three others that had around 100MB each.

Comment: Ubuntu can't install into a NTFS partition. Wipe D: and leave it as unallocated, and Ubuntu will install fine. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to boot your installation media in legacy-mode. Your drive is MBR-partitioned.

The Installer will give you options how to install. Choose "Something else".

Look for the 97GB-partition and choose it as target for your installation, you have to format it to ext3 or ext4. Mount-point is "/".

When the installer asks where to install Grub (the boot-loader) your answer is sda.

After reboot you will be greeted with the Grub-menu which lets you choose the operating-system to boot up.

Comment: Without more information, there's no way that you can be sure that sda3 is the partition you want to format. The partitions could have been created out of order, and without a gparted view, you could get it really wrong. Cheers, Al